# Licence plate enhancement

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, opencv, ocr, enhancement

Is it possible to enhance the image below and make it more readable?

[image]

I have tried apply binarization but there is some kind of shadow.

[image]

So I have tried to convert image to gray scale and then equalization

[image]

It is better, but still there is a problem with shadow and international vehicle registration code is not readable.

Comment: Sure, algorithms/filters exist to do such things. What research have you done on the topic? What are you trying to do? If you’re simply asking if that image could be made more readable, the answer is likely yes. If you’re looking for a more thoughtful answer, it might be beneficial to change your question to have more direction/content than it currently has

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried several algorithms but maybe I have wrong direction. I have tried contrast stretching, CLAHE algorithm and some kind of threshold. I don't know if there are another algorithm/filter that can be used.

Comment: Binarization with Otsu method? Local binarization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess *image denoising* and *image super-resolution* techniques could be used to enhance license plate images. 
Here are a few relevant links:

1. Image denoising based - [SNIDER: Single Noisy Image Denoising and Rectification for Improving License Plate Recognition](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/336372247_SNIDER_Single_Noisy_Image_Denoising_and_Rectification_for_Improving_License_Plate_Recognition)
2. Image super-resolution based - [Multiframe Superresolution of Vehicle License Plates Based on Distribution Estimation Approach](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jcse/2016/4194309/)